# Visual Studio 2012 compile .c files as cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I can set visual studio to compile .c files as cpp files as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx But this is a compiler option. I wonder if there is a way to point several .c files only and not to effect on compilation option in general.

Comment: In 2008 you can set properties per file. Maybe in 2012 it works too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select specific source file(s) and select the compiler yourself.

Properties dialog box (selected option is **Advanced**):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a per-file option, it doesn't necessarily apply to *every* .c file in your project.  Just right-click the file in the Solution Explorer window to make it selective.  Note that you can hold down the Ctrl key while clicking files to set this option on a group of files.